# Git Exclude Commiting the Database File

Tags: php, git

I am using Laravel and working with a team of three. The local set up for database would be different for each of his in terms of database.

So i want to ignore the database config file to be committed. When i do a `git status` i always see the database.php file in the list. How can i tell GIT to ignore it complete from committing or downloading the initial commit from bitbucket as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git update-index --assume-unchanged app/config/database.php`

Comment: so if someone updates the file online also it doesnt download it?

Comment: This is more of a makeshift solution. Ideally you would remove the database.php file from the repository entirely, and place a template-file (e.g. `database.php.template`) there instead. Then you can do what fedorqui suggested. Each time you clone the repository, you copy the `database.php.template` to `database.php`, and adjust your settings.